# Delay messages until connection complete?

Tags: c#

I'm using [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck). I'm unsure if this is a flaw in their design or my code but messages are received before I've had chance to connect the user, which makes it pretty difficult to resolve a client to work with upon receiving data, when we haven't registered it.

Here is how I connect and receive:

```
private void OnClientConnected(IWebSocketConnection connection)
{
    var clientId = connection.ConnectionInfo.Id;
    var networkClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient(clientId, connection);
    
    _clientRepository.AddClient(clientId, networkClient);
}

private async void OnDataReceived(byte[] data, IWebSocketConnection connection)
{
    var clientId = connection.ConnectionInfo.Id;
    var (found, client) = _clientRepository.TryGetByGuid(clientId);

    if (!found || client == null)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Failed to resolve network client from connected GUID");
        return;
    }

    await client.OnReceivedAsync(data);
}
```

It hits the error where its unable to resolve it from the GUID because we haven't registered it into the repository yet.

If I add a delay to the top of `OnDataReceived` like:
`await Task.Delay(100);`
It works fine...

How can I override this little flaw without delaying messages uneccessarily?

Comment: You could use a producer-consumer design pattern, where the consumer would not only wait until there are messages available, but also wait until the client is stored.